Is there support for computing confidence intervals for Wilcoxon Test in Python?
Introduction/Summary of Problem
I'm working on a project with an intention of computing one-sample confidence intervals about the mean for several variables of interest in my dataset. After performing qualitative and quantitative approaches to assessing normality, I believe that the analyses can benefit from using both parametric and non-parametric hypothesis testing methods. However, I have been unable to locate Python routines that compute the confidence interval about the mean for a Wilcoxon Test.
Efforts to Identify Solutions
Now, with regards to implementation of hypothesis testing methods in Python, I have identified the following:
scipy.stats.ttest_1samp().confidence interval(confidence_level=arg)

which performs an independent t-test and returns the test statistic, p-value, and bounds of the confidence interval for a specified confidence level. With respect to the non-parametric Wilcoxon Test, there are near identical methods for performing the test provided by scipy.stats and pingouin that are scipy.stats.wilcoxon/ scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu and pingouin.wilcoxon/pingouin.mwu, respectively. However, none of these methods appear to offer support for computing confidence intervals. I've also searched both Stackoverflow and Stack Exchange thoroughly and have not been able to come across any submissions with solutions on this concern.
I'm aware of the formula for a one-sample confidence interval about a population mean. However, I have not been able to locate a Python routine or a formula for computing the critical value (with df = n - 1) for a Wilcoxon Test in Python given a specific level of confidence and given the tailed condition of the test.
Conclusion
Therefore, I'm inquiring about whether Python offers support for computing confidence intervals about the mean for a Wilcoxon Test and the formula for computing the critical value of a Wilcoxon Test statistic that would permit me to compute the confidence interval manually.
Brief disclaimer: The author imported their submission from a LaTEX editor in Overleaf, so the submission was only contained within the image attachment. The text above was extracted from that image.


Can you avoid using images for the text in your question? Doing so makes this unsearchable, which makes it substantially less useful to future users. Using images for LaTeX equations is fine -  but can you restrict your use of images to only that?

This bioinformatics post suggests a bootstrapping-based method for computing the confidence interval: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/10580/confidence-interval-with-wilcoxon-test-in-python-for-log-normal-distribution

Another option for computing a CI about the median which is nonparametric but avoids bootstrapping is scipy.stats.quantile_test.
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
rng = np.random.default_rng(39891409235034)
dist = stats.levy()
x = dist.rvs(size=100)
res = stats.quantile_test(x, p=0.5)
res.confidence_interval()
# ConfidenceInterval(low=1.3013651046612258, high=3.5638397384022906)

I have no other suggestions for "computing a CI about a population mean using a nonparametric approach" other than using bootstrap, which can of course be used for the mean instead of the median.

Hey Matt, thanks for the recommendation for a nonparametric approach without bootstrapping! I'll give this a go.

Which version of scipy.stats supports this routine? I'm getting an attribute error when attempting to import it using version 1.10.1 of scipy. I'm also working in a python 3.8.0 environment which seems incompatible with scipy version 1.13.1.

1.12.0 (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/release/1.12.0-notes.html#scipy-stats-improvements).

Every time I look at this issue something new comes to mind: if you know the standard deviation or have a reliable estimate, Chebyshev's Inequality could provide a nonparametric confidence interval for the mean. https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/17690 mentioned some related formulas for when both the mean and variance are estimated, but I haven't found one for the true mean and estimated variance. You might ask at Cross Validated https://stats.stackexchange.com/ for other options.

Hey Matt, I wanted to revisit this topic as I'm developing a write-up where I have an intention of reporting the formula used for a confidence interval based upon the Quantile Test. I read through the scipy.stats documentation and found that "The approach to confidence intervals is attributed to Thompson [3]...." with an equation for the probability of a quantile being larger than the value of an observation. However, without buying the book that it references, it's unclear to me how this probability formula is incorporated into the C.I. formula. Are you able to shed more light on this?

The formula there is the survival function of a binomial distribution. Note that "the proportion of the population less than q is p", so if the observations are IID samples from some distribution, then the observed number of observations less than q is governed by the binomial distribution with probability p. From here, you can reason your way to confidence intervals, but that is a better answered on Cross Validated.

Matt, thanks for the breakdown of the survival function. I understand that the function is treated as a CDF using a Binomial Distribution. However, I'm not familiar with how one would go about "reasoning their way" to a confidence interval. Are there other developers of scipy.stats.quantile_test() that you would be able to point me towards that have a firm grasp of the expression that governs the confidence interval calculation in this test? I'm questioning its power and legitimacy given that the documentation does not provide an explicit formula, nor how to arrive at one.

Post a question at https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/12680. The comments of a stack overflow post are not great for technical discussion.

If you are interested in the Wilcoxon test, I think you are looking for a confidence interval about the median, not the mean. As for why, take a look at the null hypothesis of the Wilcoxon test, and check out the confidence interval returned by R's wilcox.test. (You also wrote some things about the critical value of the test statistic, but that does not have an interpretation at all similar to the mean or median, so you'll have to update your question if that's what you're interested in.)
As a pathological example of when you might be more interested in the median than the mean, suppose your data is Levy-distributed (specifically according to scipy.stats.levy). The median is a little above 2:
from scipy import stats
dist = stats.levy()
dist.median()
# 2.1981093383177326

and the PDF looks innocuous:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 300)
y = dist.pdf(x)
plt.plot(x, y)


but the distribution is heavy-tailed, and the mean of the distribution is infinite, so we can't expect the confidence interval about the mean to be very useful. To investigate, let's start by drawing 1000 samples from Levy, each with 100 observations.
rng = np.random.default_rng(39891409235034)
dist = stats.levy()
x = dist.rvs(size=(1000, 100))

Here is a histogram of the sample means:
plt.plot(np.mean(x, axis=-1))


They are all over the map. (Look at the scale on the y-axis.) Just to confirm that the confidence interval about the mean doesn't tell us anything useful here:
res = stats.ttest_1samp(x, popmean=0, axis=-1)
l, h = res.confidence_interval()
# the confidence intervals are very wide
# and none contain the true mean (infinity)
np.mean(h-l), np.std(h-l), np.median(h-l)
# (1330469.7780494413, 20391884.85861377, 658.5811329596786)

However, scipy.stats.bootstrap can be used to compute a 95% confidence interval about the median.
res = stats.bootstrap((x,), np.median, axis=-1, batch=100)

And we can confirm that the confidence interval contains the true median for approximately 95% of those samples:
l, h = res.confidence_interval
median = dist.median()
np.sum((l < median) & (h > median))
# 952


Hello Matt,
Thanks for the thorough interpretation and feedback on my question! You alluded to the need to use a "nonparametric test for the mean" given interest in computing a CI about a population mean which is currently my focus. Can you provide details on recommended methods for computing a CI about a population mean using a nonparametric approach that does not involve using a biased measure like Wilcoxon Rank Sum that, as you mentioned, provides a CI about the median not mean location parameter?

Thanks for the recommendation of using bootstrapping, I can see that bootstrapping can be a good approximation for computing the CI about the median given lack of support for Python routines that compute this directly, however, I would elect to use R if I were to move forward with using Wilcoxon's CI about the median given that one of the controls in my problem is to not use resampling, only authoritative data. But if you could point me towards a formula that would allow me to compute the CI about a mean for nonparametric test directly, I would be comfortable with coding it directly. Thanks!

One last thing, which tool did you use to parse through the image attachment to create an equivalent textual submission? I appreciate your help and it would be great to work with this moving forward!

I don't remember which tool I used. I just searched for "image to text online" or something and picked the first result. In response to your other questions, I only have one more thing to offer here without doing research: I forgot that we added a nonparametric quantile confidence interval to SciPy - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.quantile_test.html. I'll add an answer with that.
